# How to open and run some commands on wsl (Windows Subsystem for Linux) by using python?

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new to python,I want to open WSL and start the program 'SAC' by typing 'sac'. and run few commands within the sac to merge some sac flies.

Hope you guys could help me with solutions!
Thanks in advance

This is the commands I  tried in my CMD, I want to execute this in python:

```
E:\WIHG\27-08-2019\gcf_conversion\SAC>wsl
vivek@DESKTOP-15521UM:/mnt/e/WIHG/27-08-2019/gcf_conversion/SAC$ sac
 SEISMIC ANALYSIS CODE [11/11/2013 (Version 101.6a)]
 Copyright 1995 Regents of the University of California
SAC> ls *_*.sac
20060501_1400z.sac  20060501_1500z.sac  20060501_1600z.sac
SAC> merge ./20060501_1400z.sac ./20060501_1500z.sac
SAC> write 20060501.sac
```

so I want something like:
(This code is to give an idea about what i am looking for)
i want to open wsl and then run sac command there to start SAC programe
execute other commands in SAC.

```
 p= subprocess(['wsl','sac'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE) 

p.stdin.write(subprocess(['ls *_*.sac'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE) )
```

so on..

Comment: What happens when you try it? and if that's not what you intended, please explain which part of the code you require assistance with.

Comment: I want to use the subprocess module of python for this! And I am trying to execute it in windows through WSL. I am new to python!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We have a general idea of what you want to do but not a specific issue / problem / requirement.
Will the files always have the same names?

Answer (score 3):

This is described in [Windows Subsystem for Linux interoperability with Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop). Anything you pass after `wsl` is passed to the Linux distro. The working directory is the current CMD/Powershell directory.

For example :

```
C:\temp> wsl ls -la
```

Returns the contents of C:\Temp.

This means you could create a shell script that calls SAC or python and have it run inside WSL instead of trying to have Python on Windows call WSL. I haven't used SAC but I suspect you could use the last example from [Calling SAC from scripts](https://ds.iris.edu/files/sac-manual/manual/sac_script.html) with wsl. If you save the script to a file, eg `myfile.sh` you may be able to call it with `wsl myfile.sh`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I thought it will be better if i could everything in python rather running a bash script in between.
Since i am not able to achieve that, I am trying your suggestion.